# How to use variables from other Activity for buttons in Custom list view Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, variables

I am currently building a bare bones game app for university. In the Shop activity of the app I have created a custom list view in order to display items in the shop. Each have a different price etc. so the buttons should all complete different tasks. Following guides I have done this through a switch statement inside my getView() method. However the variables used within these statements are required from the shop activity and I was just wondering if anyone could let me know how to use these variables within my custom adapter. Any help would be great, im rather new to this.

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] listText;
    int[] listImage;

    LayoutInflater inflater;



    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context ctx, String [] itemList, int [] imageList, Button []
            ButtonList){

        this.context = ctx;
        this.listText = itemList;
        this.listImage = imageList;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listText.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_list_view, null);
        TextView txtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageIcon);
        Button buttonInd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
        txtView.setText(listText[position]);
        itemImg.setImageResource(listImage[position]);

        buttonInd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        if (firstB==false){
                            if(gold>=1000){
                                firstB = true;
                                gold = gold - 1000;
                                dmgMultiplier = dmgMultiplier *2;
                                setDataShop(dmgMultiplier, gold, LoggedInUser);
                                setDataShopBought(firstbBin, secondbBin,
                                        thirdbBin,forthbBin,
                                        fithbBin,sixthbBin,
                                        seventhbBin,LoggedInUser);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (secondB==false){
                            if(gold>=3000){
                                secondB = true;
                                gold = gold - 3000;
                                dmgMultiplier = dmgMultiplier *5;
                                Shop.setDataShop(dmgMultiplier, gold, LogIn.getUser());
                                Shop.setDataShopBought(firstbBin, secondbBin,
                                        thirdbBin,forthbBin,
                                        fithbBin,sixthbBin,
                                        seventhbBin,LoggedInUser);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (thirdB==false){
                            if(gold>=8000){
                                thirdB = true;
                                gold = gold - 8000;
                                dmgMultiplier = dmgMultiplier *10;
                                Shop.setDataShop(dmgMultiplier, gold, LogIn.getUser());
                                Shop.setDataShopBought(firstbBin, secondbBin,
                                        thirdbBin,forthbBin,
                                        fithbBin,sixthbBin,
                                        seventhbBin,LoggedInUser);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (fourthB==false){
                            if(gold>=12000){
                                fourthB = true;
                                gold = gold - 12000;
                                dmgMultiplier = dmgMultiplier *15;
                                Shop.setDataShop(dmgMultiplier, gold, LogIn.getUser());
                                Shop.setDataShopBought(firstbBin, secondbBin,
                                        thirdbBin,forthbBin,
                                        fithbBin,sixthbBin,
                                        seventhbBin,LoggedInUser);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (fithB==false){
                            if(gold>=20000){
                                fithB = true;
                                gold = gold - 20000;
                                dmgMultiplier = dmgMultiplier *30;
                                Shop.setDataShop(dmgMultiplier, gold, LogIn.getUser());
                                Shop.setDataShopBought(firstbBin, secondbBin,
                                        thirdbBin,forthbBin,
                                        fithbBin,sixthbBin,
                                        seventhbBin,LoggedInUser);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (sixB==false){
                            if(gold>=40000){
                                sixB = true;
                                gold = gold - 40000;
                                dmgMultiplier = dmgMultiplier *60;
                                Shop.setDataShop(dmgMultiplier, gold, LogIn.getUser());
                                Shop.setDataShopBought(firstbBin, secondbBin,
                                        thirdbBin,forthbBin,
                                        fithbBin,sixthbBin,
                                        seventhbBin,LoggedInUser);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        if (sevenB==false){
                            if(gold>=100000){
                                sevenB = true;
                                gold = gold - 100000;
                                dmgMultiplier = dmgMultiplier *150;
                                Shop.setDataShop(dmgMultiplier, gold, LogIn.getUser());
                                Shop.setDataShopBought(firstbBin, secondbBin,
                                        thirdbBin,forthbBin,
                                        fithbBin,sixthbBin,
                                        seventhbBin,LoggedInUser);
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it bad practice to do calculation and logic in the adapter.

One way to do it is you can create a click listener interface:

```
public interface CustomItemClickListener {
     void onClick(int position);
}
```

Your ShopActivity can implement this interface:

```
public ShopActivity extends Activity implements CustomItemClickListener {
    
    ...
    private CustomBaseAdapter adapter;
  
    @Override void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        adapter = CustomBaseAdapter(this, itemList, imageList, this)
    }

    @Override void onClick(int position){
        //Your switch code block here.
    }
}
```

And your adapter class:

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] listText;
    int[] listImage;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    CustomItemClickListener listener;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context ctx, String[] itemList, int[] imageList, CustomItemClickListener listener){

        this.context = ctx;
        this.listText = itemList;
        this.listImage = imageList;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.listener = listener;

    }
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        buttonInd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onClick(position);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the response, however I just wanted to know if in the shop section where you used CustomAdapter, was this supposed to be custom base adapter?

Comment: @SnuffyWasTaken Yes, it is. I just updated my answer.